# Arrange the data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 16500 rows and 1 column data in my file. I want 1st 50 rows data in 1st column then next 50 rows data in 2nd column likewise continue for my all data set. How can I do this in matlab.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an `x` of size 16500x1, all you would need to do `y = reshape(x,50,[]);`

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your answer.